# How to make discord.js read reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently developing a discord.js bot on the latest version. I'm currently trying to get the following bit of code to send a message giving instructions with what to say, then once I get a response, send another message. however, I can't get it working. any help would be appreciated!

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  //check if message is from self
  if (message.author === client.user) {
    //if it is. do nothing
    return
  } else {
    //if its not, read message
    if (message.content === prefix + "start") {
      let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
      message.channel.send("Testing.. Type YES or NO").then(() => {
        message.channel
          .awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time']
          })
          .then(message => {
            message = message.first()
            if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'YES' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
              message.channel.send(`Hello World!`);
            } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'NO' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'N') {
              message.channel.send(`Ping`);
            } else {
              message.channel.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`);
            }
          })
          .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send('Timeout');
          });
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Should messageContent not check for starting rather than the whole message content.. e.g. `message.content.startsWith(prefix + "start")` ? Does it actually get into that conditional and attempt to send?

Comment: it does send the message "Testing.. Type YES or NO" but it doesn't respond to "YES" or "NO" only "start" I know its doing that because of the if statement however removing it yields no results @SandyGarrido

Answer (score 2):

Scoping problems. The result of your `awaitMessages()` promise is called `message`. However, the outer scope of the function itself has a variable named `message` as well, hence you are referencing different things:

```js
        // from client.on("messageCreate", message)
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
              max: 1,
              time: 30000,
              errors: ['time']
            })
            // not the same; from awaitMessages() instead
            .then(message => {
              message = message.first()
            })
```

You can fix it by doing this:

```js
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
})
// we call it 'collected' as we essentially collect a message
.then(collected => {
    // redeclare a new variable named 'msg'
    const msg = collected.first()
    if (msg.content.toUppercase() == "YES" || msg.content.toUppercase() == "Y") {
        msg.channel.send(`Hello World!`);
    }
    else if (...)
```

You get the gist here.

Comment: this didn't seem to fix the issue, it still doesn't seem to get past
```js
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
})
```
It seems like something there is keeping it from progressing any further, I removed the whole thing from the if (message.content === prefix + "start") statement as that was causing some problems.

Comment: After removing the prefix filter, did that work?

Comment: it did not, it sends the initial message prompting to say yes or no then after that it doesnt seem to pass the YES or NO past the above mentioned code